# Can I write a script to do the manual Salesforce operations?

Tags: deployment, admin

I'm reading through Salesforce's suggestion on how to keep your environments synchronized.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/migrate_manual.htm

In other environments, one writes a script, and applied that script to the various environments.  Rather than performing GUI operations over and over.  That results in repeatability, and the ability to put the script in git.

Is there a script interface to Salesforce, as well as a GUI interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script here implies using ANT tool and  [force.com migration tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm) .

Metadata in salesforce can be deployed to various salesforce environments using force.com migration tool .

Migration tool comes with build.xml and build.properties .You can use this to automate the deployment process.

Most of  configuration done is SFDC will be available as metadata xml which can be deployed via ANT and force.com migration tool .

In short script interface means using force.com migration tool for metadata and using data loader or apex scripts for data migration

For the components that are not supported via metadata .There are web browser automation tools like Selenium,Helium ,Ranorex,etc

All these adds an additional complexity and should be used only if there is real business need to automate unsupported metadata types

Comment: Mohith, I think I attended your talk at Midwest Dream last week, and really enjoyed it!  I mean the bits that are not otherwise covered by scripting tools, like mail merge templates.  Those things have to be done by automating the browser interaction, in a player-piano fashion.  I was thinking Expect, but Salesforce thinks in terms of Selenium.

Comment: Ah I think your question is bit unclear :) .You should mention here that for the components that are not supported via metadata .Selenium is just an example .There are many more like Helium ,Ranorex,etc .You can use any browser based tools but generally Ids may change from environment to environment and hence hard to maintain and test

Answer (score 1):

Aha!  Salesforce recommends, or at least mentions, Selenium.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.dev_lifecycle.meta/dev_lifecycle/lifecycle_adv_unsupported_metadata.htm

Comment: Please do not post link only answers - put a quick description of what the link refers to.